# NameError: name 'input_shape' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

heyy guys im beginner at deep learning and currently trying basic cnn that i found to make model

but i got some error that said

> ```
>  49 tensorboard=TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(time()))
> ```
>
> ---> 50 model = ClassicalModel(input_shape)
> 51 model.fit_generator(
> 52     train_generator,
>
> NameError: name 'input_shape' is not defined

with code

```
import os
from imutils import paths
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from time import time
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense


IM_WIDTH=224
IM_HEIGHT=224
EPOCH=2
batch_size=32

ORIG_INPUT_DATASET="/content/drive/MyDrive/DataFix/DataJadi"
BASE_PATH="/content/drive/MyDrive/DataFix/DataJadi/"

TRAIN_PATH = os.path.sep.join([BASE_PATH, "training"])
VAL_PATH = os.path.sep.join([BASE_PATH, "validation"])

totalTrain = len(list(paths.list_images(TRAIN_PATH)))
totalVal = len(list(paths.list_images(VAL_PATH)))

def ClassicalModel(input_shape):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy', metris=['accuracy'])
  
  return model

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1 / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True
)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_PATH,
                                                    target_size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT),
                                                    batch_size=batch_size,
                                                    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    VAL_PATH,
    target_size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical'
)
tensorboard=TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(time()))
model = ClassicalModel(input_shape)
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=totalTrain // batch_size,
    epochs=EPOCH,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=totalVal // batch_size,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=[tensorboard])
model.save_weights('GerakanUjian.h5')
model.save('GerakanUjian.h5')
```

i already add the input_shape in `def classicalModel` but it seems does not work
any answer would be appreciated
thank you so much

Comment: Your `input_shape` variable is not defined pass something like this : `ClassicalModel((batch_size, IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `def classicalModel(input_size)` is a function definition. For it to work, you have to pass a valid `input_shape` to it when you call it. In a nutshell, something like this should work:

```
model = classicalModel(input_shape=(batch_size, IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT))
```

You have to define how the input to your model would look like